# Failed to find package in third party repository

Tags: debian, sql

I'm new to debian & linux, and I want to know how to download packages from third party repositories.

Specifically, I want to download a Microsoft SQL driver into a docker container [(guide)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

First I add a security key using apt-key

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
```

Then I add the Microsoft package repository to the list of places for apt to look

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
```

Finally I try and download the package

```
apt-get install msodbcsql17
```

I get the error

> `Unable to locate package msodbcsql17`

What can I do to fix this?  I see the package at https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod/pool/main/m/ but I guess apt cannot find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you add a new repository, you need to update your apt cache so it will see the updated/new packages:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then you can run your install command as normal.